# When checking the count of rows resulting from a query, does the entire subquery have to execute?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that is taking a long time to execute, so I want to count the number of rows to see how large the output is. I will prospectively use the following format:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
    (Original_Query) AS COUNT_QUERY
```

Original_Query is serving as a placeholder for an actual query. Does Original_Query have to run in its entirety before I can obtain the count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query definitely run in such case. One option to get the result without running is to look on the result estimation in the compiled execution plan. Simply run this command before your query:

```
SET SHOWPLAN_ALL ON
```

If you run your query then you get the query plan together with the estimates instead of your query result. It is possible to use it even programmatically.

See for example [this](https://www.red-gate.com/library/inside-the-sql-server-query-optimizer) excellent book for details.

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment.

Yes.  The entire query has to run.  How else would you be able to get the exact count?  After all, you have written a query.  When you tell SQL Server to run it, you expect it to run.

You can look at the execution plan to get estimates of the number of rows.  For a complicated query, this is probably not going to be very accurate.